# What are the minimum altitudes for each warp level?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

The higher warp factors have a minimum altitude requirement.

What is the lowest altitude at which each warp is allowed?

Comment: Is there a particular body you're curious about? The altitudes are different on every body in the system.

Comment: @SaintWacko I'd like to know them all, but Kerbin is the most interesting.

Comment: [Kerbin warp limits](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Kerbin#Reference_frames). There should be similar tables for other bodies, but I have no idea if it was updated this year. Hint: there are no time warp limits in Tracking Station view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### KERBOL

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           3 270 000 m
10×          3 270 000 m
50×          6 540 000 m
100×        13 080 000 m
1 000×      26 160 000 m
10 000×     52 320 000 m
100 000×    65 400 000 m
```

---

### MOHO

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           10 000 m
10×          10 000 m
50×          30 000 m
100×         50 000 m
1 000×      100 000 m
10 000×     200 000 m
100 000×    300 000 m
```

---

### EVE

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           90 000 m (above the atmosphere)
10×          90 000 m (above the atmosphere)
50×          90 000 m (above the atmosphere)
100×        120 000 m
1 000×      240 000 m
10 000×     480 000 m
100 000×    600 000 m
```

### *GILLY*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×            8 000 m
10×           8 000 m
50×           8 000 m
100×         20 000 m
1 000×       40 000 m
10 000×      80 000 m
100 000×    100 000 m
```

---

### KERBIN

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           70 000 m (above the atmosphere)
10×          70 000 m (above the atmosphere)
50×          70 000 m (above the atmosphere)
100×        120 000 m
1 000×      240 000 m
10 000×     480 000 m
100 000×    600 000 m
```

### *MÜN*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×            5 000 m
10×           5 000 m
50×          10 000 m
100×         25 000 m
1 000×       50 000 m
10 000×     100 000 m
100 000×    200 000 m
```

### *MINMUS*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           3 000 m
10×          3 000 m
50×          6 000 m
100×        12 000 m
1 000×      24 000 m
10 000×     48 000 m
100 000×    60 000 m
```

---

### DUNA

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           50 000 m (above the atmosphere)
10×          50 000 m (above the atmosphere)
50×          60 000 m
100×        100 000 m
1 000×      300 000 m
10 000×     600 000 m
100 000×    800 000 m
```

### *IKE*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×            5 000 m
10×           5 000 m
50×          10 000 m
100×         25 000 m
1 000×       50 000 m
10 000×     100 000 m
100 000×    200 000 m
```

---

### DRES

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           10 000 m
10×          10 000 m
50×          30 000 m
100×         50 000 m
1 000×      100 000 m
10 000×     200 000 m
100 000×    300 000 m
```

---

### JOOL

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×            200 000 m (above the atmosphere)
10×           200 000 m (above the atmosphere)
50×           200 000 m (above the atmosphere)
100×          200 000 m (above the atmosphere)
1 000×        300 000 m
10 000×       600 000 m
100 000×    1 200 000 m
```

### *LAYTHE*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           50 000 m (above the atmosphere)
10×          50 000 m (above the atmosphere)
50×          60 000 m
100×        120 000 m
1 000×      240 000 m
10 000×     480 000 m
100 000×    600 000 m
```

### *VALL*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           24 500 m
10×          24 500 m
50×          24 500 m
100×         40 000 m
1 000×       60 000 m
10 000×      80 000 m
100 000×    100 000 m
```

### *TYLO*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           30 000 m
10×          30 000 m
50×          60 000 m
100×        120 000 m
1 000×      240 000 m
10 000×     480 000 m
100 000×    600 000 m
```

### *BOP*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           24 500 m
10×          24 500 m
50×          24 500 m
100×         40 000 m
1 000×       60 000 m
10 000×      80 000 m
100 000×    100 000 m
```

### *POL*

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×           5 000 m
10×          5 000 m
50×          5 000 m
100×         8 000 m
1 000×      12 000 m
10 000×     30 000 m
100 000×    90 000 m
```

---

### EELOO

```
Warp        Minimum Altitude
1×          Any
5×            4 000 m
10×           4 000 m
50×          20 000 m
100×         30 000 m
1 000×       40 000 m
10 000×      70 000 m
100 000×    150 000 m
```